# React Native Blob is not a Function

Tags: react-native, blob, react-native-fetch-blob

I'm trying to create a blob in React Native using LaunchImageLibrary. My basic component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker'


const Home = () => {

  const getImageFromLibrary = async () => {
    const result = await launchImageLibrary()

    const { uri } = result.assets[0]
    console.log(uri)
    // result: file:///Users/myMac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7287EC81-054B-401E-942D-3978C6E308AF/data/Containers/Data/Application/6098A1CE-D49C-4ECD-8396-29BD0E8C598D/tmp/DBCF7839-8076-4D9A-8773-0F701EB58E0E.jpg

    const fetchedFile = await fetch(uri)
    console.log('FETCHED: ', fetchedFile)
    const blob =  await fetchedFile.blob()
    console.log('BLOB: ', blob)
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Button onPress={getImageFromLibrary} title="Get from library" />    
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: fetchedFile.blob is not a function
```

I see other people able to use `fetchedFile.blob()` without any problem and I'm not sure why I'm having issues. I'm using an M1 mac, running iOS 15.5 emulator (iPhone13), using a create-react-app via npx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Native Fetch API implementation which is based on `whatwg-fetch` in some scenario feel buggy when you work with a large chunk of data like bitmap files.

Alternative solution is using  `XMLHttpRequest` API.

```js
const getImageFromLibrary = async () => {
  const result = await launchImageLibrary();

  const { uri } = result.assets[0];
  console.log(uri);
  // result: file:///Users/myMac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7287EC81-054B-401E-942D-3978C6E308AF/data/Containers/Data/Application/6098A1CE-D49C-4ECD-8396-29BD0E8C598D/tmp/DBCF7839-8076-4D9A-8773-0F701EB58E0E.jpg

  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  // Upload BLOB data to remote server...

  // We're done with the blob, close and release it
  blob.close();
};
```

Comment: Wow thanks man that worked! I'm getting back "blob.close is not a function". If I don't close the connection does that cause a memory leak?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in calling  `blob.close()` . Check new solution edit

Comment: Doesn't it lose the scope of blob when you move out outside?

Comment: Oooh, I see.  Can you try to check typeof blob after uploading file.

Comment: Try to Switch JavaScript engine from `JavaScriptCore` to `Hermes` or vice versa

Comment: I think the request will close on its own after the response is sent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099211/does-xmlhttprequest-object-close-after-response-received. Seems like you can just do without the "blob.close()" part if you want to edit it

Comment: I think that we can not guarantee that the request has automatically closed. you can optionally call `blob?.close()` when exist to avoid runtime error